# Meaning of "amends a court" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

I'm need to translate this sentence:

> Critics at the assembly said that this was because of what they see at
>   the lack of progress on Russia's part in the hearing to its
>   commitments, such as amends a court for instance

But I don't understand this part:

> such as amends a court for instance

Can someone explain this?
**Added**
If it helps, it's from this video: 
https://youtu.be/tGggPyg7QbA?t=21s

Comment: It sounds quite clunky. Do you have a source for more context?

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, she's saying [*such as **the Minsk Accord***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk_II) (i.e. - the ***agreement**, on a package of measures to alleviate the ongoing war in the Donbass region of Ukraine*, reached at the summit in Minsk on 11 February 2015. I retain a relatively open mind as to whether this type of question is On Topic or not (but I'm inclined to think probably not, since it's hard to see how it will help *future* visitors).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It'll help future visitors if they'll stuck at the same problem of speach transcription. They'll likely guess to listen for any city or country in the speech. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @mr4eshi: But it's a complete one-off! Besides which, even if someone else stumbles over exactly the same footage, I don't see how they're going to find this existing Q + A. Plus [as per this meta answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1034/126), it might well be considered a type of *proofreading*, which is definitely Off Topic. I'll wait and see what others have to say (or maybe post a meta question myself).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Ok, I got your point now. I'll try to close my question. But can you point me to the resource I could get help from?

Comment: I haven't closevoted (nor has anyone else, as yet). You might not be able to delete it anyway (because it's been *answered*), and if you *did*, that would prevent me from citing it as an example of a type of question I'd like to be considered on meta (is it On Topic or not?). I think your chances of finding a free site to help you with such transcription are very low (why would anyone give up their time for such ephemeral matters?). But you might get useful responses if you try posting in "chat" here (I think you just need to earn 50 rep points before you can get in there! :)

Comment: Ok. I'm really gratefull for your help, answers and advice. I'll do my best on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're transcribing a video, then translating? She says "Critics at the assembly said that this was because of what they see as a lack of progress on Russia's part in adhering to its commitments, such as the *emits* a court, for instance..."

This is a Latin phrase I'm not familiar with, and I don't think I transcribed it right, either. Here's the source for others: http://bloooo.com/2015/03/pace-suspends-russia39s-voting-rights-until-april-over-conflict-in-ukraine/

Edit: FumbleFingers got it, it's the Minsk Accord.

Comment: Yes, I'm to transcribe and thanslate this video. "Emits a court"... May be. I'll work for that mater. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it's a *Latin* phrase?

Comment: Shoot, no, you got it, thanks. If it was court, though, then any words I'm not familiar with would likely be French or Latin, as many legal terms are. Do you mind submitting your comment as an answer to make sure he sees it?

Comment: Per my comment, although I haven't *actually* closevoted, that's the way I'm leaning. And I'm not sure I believe it's sensible to post *answers* to questions that should be closed. The OP gets inbox notification of all comments to the Q anyway.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm a relatively new user, so I don't even have the ability to close vote yet.

Comment: I've been here since the site started, but I still only get one vote the same as you when it comes to deciding what we consider On Topic. [This meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/) is related, but not quite the same thing. If you (or anyone else) asks for a "community vote" on meta about these exact type of questions, and the majority are in favour of allowing them, I will fall into line. But as of right now I'm just "ambivalent", and waiting to be persuaded either way.